# expo init <project name> throwing npm ERROR (windows OS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

Just started with expo and React-Native and when I run
`expo init ProjectName`
I am getting an error stating: 
`Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...,"version":"7.0.0-bet'`
`Process exited with non-zero code: 1`
`Set EXPO_DEBUG=true in your env to view the stack trace.` 
 
When I add the said thing in env (using `set EXPO_DEBUG=true` on windows), I get the following error: 
`Error: Process exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.child.on (C:\Users\mohit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\@expo\spawn-async\build\spawnAsync.js:39:21)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (C:\Users\mohit\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\expo-cli\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:29)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)`
 It's something related to 'spawn-async'. I was also getting issues with 'spawn' sometime earlier while creating a node-server...but I resolved that there and then using 'exec' instead. Tried to find this on expo forums and even in react-native issues but couldn't find a solution. Can someone plz suggest something? Is it some "windows" thing only or something related to npm releases?

P.S: I also ran `create-react-native-app ProjectName` and again got a similar kind of error about end of JSON input!

Comment: Could you please show us your `package.json`? I guess there should be `"` instead of `'` somewhere

Comment: @mpasko256 Thanks for replying, but I didn't get your question. I used the command `expo init`. So it would initialize the `package.json` for me...right? Still here I am providing a link to that and also to the complete log for this error. Personally I think it's something related to `npm`. Thanks!
ERROR LOG: [link](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=02140715420519755212)
PACKAGE.JSON: [link](https://ideone.com/vZg1wG)

Answer (score 0):

Now I know what can be the issue, it can be just the trivial one:

- Please update `node` an `npm` to the newest available version and please `init` you project again in different directory.

Answer (score 0):

- You'll need to have **Node.js** (version 10 or newer) installed on
  your computer. [Download the latest version of Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/).
- Additionally, you'll need **Git** to create new projects with Expo
  CLI. [You can download Git from here](https://git-scm.com/).

Make sure that you have installed these two things in your device.

[***Go to doc for expo installation***](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/introduction/installation)

Answer (score 0):

in my case. make sure you have yarn installed and update tour android studio packages, for it to work